# Cannot install Xcode 10 Network Link Conditioner in macOS Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10, macos-mojave

I'm using the final version of Xcode 10 on macOS Mojave beta 11. I downloaded the Additional Tools for Xcode 10 package [from Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode).

When I try to install the Network Link Conditioner Preference Pane, Settings.app displays this error:

> “Network Link Conditioner” preferences is installed with macOS and can’t be replaced.

However, the preference pane is **not visible** inside Settings.app. I even checked under `/Library/PreferencePanes` - it's not there.

[image]

How can I get around this?

Comment: it was in your own Prefpanes directory at ~/Library/PreferencePanes and apparently those don't show up in System Preferences anymore

Comment: @MartijnScheffer It seems like that is the case, yes. I've added this information to my answer.

Comment: Network Link Conditioner doesn't work on Catalina (Correct Answer by KMT on Oct 25, 2019 8:30 AM). See at 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125000

Answer (score 242, accepted):

I ended up **manually copying** the `.prefPane` file to:

```
/Library/PreferencePanes
```

After restarting Settings.app, it finally appeared on the list and worked perfectly.

[As Martijn Scheffer stated in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414375/cannot-install-xcode-10-network-link-conditioner-in-macos-mojave#comment96831502_52414375), the reason for the pane not appearing in System Preferences is that the installer incorrectly puts the file to `~/Library/PreferencePanes` instead of `/Library/PreferencePanes`.

Download in https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ *Additional Tools for Xcode 10.1*

[image]

[image]

Comment: a bug by Apple? :)

Comment: in my system "java control panel" was already present in that location, maybe that caused the issue?

Comment: Good one. I needed to replace the preference pane with a newly downloaded one, restart Settings and finally open the file in the /Library/PreferencePanes folder

Comment: Same problem here, thanks for the workaround! Unfortunately, the pane doesn’t play well with the dark mode 

Answer (score 40):

Network Link Conditioner is already installed but you can't see it on the Settings App.
This worked for me:

1. Press Command + Space to open spotlight
2. Search for `Network Link Conditioner`
3. It will appear on the result, click on it and it will open Settings
   app.
4. `Network Link Conditioner` is now visible in the Settings App. Open it
   from the Settings app.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

+1 to brainray, what worked for me was:

1. Download new Network Link Conditioner
2. Replace the old one in /Library/PreferencePanes
3. Open Network Link Conditioner directly from /Library/PreferencePanes

It now appears in my Settings app

Answer (score 4):

In case the NLC is freezing when turning it on in the preferences it's important to note that it has to run as admin.

With the following command the preference app from MacOS can be started as admin:

```
sudo /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Preferences
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36445625/4417912

Comment: System Preferences.app moved to `/System/Applications/` in Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

Update on the answer **June 2019 Xcode 10.2**

> Apple has moved Network Link Conditioner Tool to additional tools for
>   Xcode

Go to the below link

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools

[image]

Install the dmg file, select hardware from installer

[image]

select Network Link conditioner prefpane
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Double clicking the `Network Link Conditioner.prefPane` in the `Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_x.dmg` worked for me - it appeared in the Settings after asking for permission to install.