# Xcode 11 No Device Conditions Available

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I trying to add [device conditions](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devdf21fe239) in my Xcode 11 so that I can simulate a slower network connection. However, when opening Devices and Simulators window and making sure my device is selected, it says that 'No Conditions Available'

[image: Devices and Simulators]

How do I make them appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this. It appears that you need to have a 'Network Link Conditioner' installed on your Mac (in my case Catalina) for the the option to appear in Devices and Simulator window. To install it, go to [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools) and download 'Additional Tools for Xcode 11'. Once downloaded, you can find it in the Hardware folder. Interestingly, when trying to install it, I received the following error:

> “Network Link Conditioner” preferences is installed with macOS and can’t be replaced.

Despite me unable to find it in preferences. Luckily there is an easy fix described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414376/1625364).

Comment: pane installed without any pain in the system's preferences - but the issue is still valid and I don't have any conditions inside Xcode... :/

Comment: Feels like the whole thing is a bit buggy to be honest... I also had another issue with the linter options disappearing after I thought I had fixed it... Anyway, after updating everything to the latest version (xcode & iphone) and a mac restart, everything was working again...

Comment: lucky you ;) still no success after updating Xcode lately

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to install the latest system software updates (Xcode Command Line Tools in my case). It worked for me.