# Xcode 11.3 "No Conditions Available"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-catalina, xcode11.3

After updating Xcode to version 11.3 device conditions options disappeared from the "Devices and Simulators" window. The issue appeared on both my computers. Everything worked fine with Xcode 11.2.

Any suggestions?

[image: No Conditions Available Screenshot]

Comment: so far I read smth about downloading "Additional tools" from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and moving preferance pane from downloaded stuff to System's... but it does not work as expected, so I'm still missing these device conditions :(

Comment: to be clear: tried e.g. stuff like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758261/xcode-11-no-device-conditions-available but without any success

Comment: @raistlin I also tried such stuff, and it won't help me too.

Comment: @raistlin try to install the latest system software updates. It worked for me.

Comment: I have the latest update already :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved after recent System Software Update of **Xcode Command Line Tools**.

Comment: I used the command line `xcode-select --install` to trigger the download and installation. At first, the conditions didn't appear... so I restarted the Mac and the iPhone. After the reboot, the conditions still didn't appear. But after a few minutes, they were available... So in the end, I don't know what made it work. Reinstalling the Xcode command line tools probably helped: +1

Comment: What worked for me is updating to the latest Xcode version and then restarting the Mac and Xcode , device conditions starts to get visible.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from your screen shot that the option "show as run destination" is not available.
This may happen, if you set as deployment target iPad instead of iPhone or universal, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049665/the-run-destination-ios-device-is-not-valid-for-running-the-scheme).

Comment: "Show as run destination" option is available. It's just not fitted on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 11.3 is no longer able to set Device Conditions on iOS 12 devices. I've just tested with 6 devices, all iOS 13 devices work, all iOS 12 devices show "No Conditions Available". I then took an iOS 12 device that wasn't allowing for device conditions to be set, upgraded it to iOS 13 and it then allowed conditions to be set. (Note, I did have to disconnect/reconnect the device after the upgrade).

Comment: did you have to set some permissions or additional features somewhere? I have iOS 13.3 (17C54) on my iPhone 11 and using Xcode 11.3 (11C29)... but still "no conditions available"

Comment: No. I'm using the same build of Xcode and iOS 13.3. Just upgrading from 12 to 13.3 (and reconnecting the phone) seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @DaveWood I'm running iOS 13.3. iPhone 11 Pro (on the screenshot) can't have iOS 12 installed ;)

Comment: @DaveWood, but you're right, device conditions only available on devices with iOS 13.